How do I know when a program is waiting for an input and then give the input through Python?
Sorry, this might look very stupid but I have a console C++ program and I need to pass input through Python. It is unexpected when this C++ program waits for an input and so I hoped I could have done this programmatically. Probably there's a way with Windows API but I'm not so knowledgeable in WinAPI. I'm with Windows 11.

@Tekins yes, but wouldn't that be effective when the program waits for an input? Maybe my code hangs somewhere...

You cannot query an I/O stream for whether the application that's reading from one is "waiting". Doesn't matter what language you use or how low level you go. You cannot do this.

Use Named Pipes for interprocess communication.

@Tekins is there a particular reason for that?
